# How to handle multiple dropdown select option in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html

Given the following `select` node:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
     <option value="car">car</option>
     <option value="scooter">scooter</option>
     <option value="bus">bus</option>
</select>
```

How can I do multi-select **without** pressing the *ctrl* key and **without** using jQuery ? I would like to achieve this using only **vanilla** Javascript. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This sounds like a task better use for `radio` buttons than a `select`.

Comment: problem here is the fact not all browsers support click on options so to make it work it would be a mess. Maybe you should use a group of checkboxes and style them to look like a select?

Comment: @AdamKonieska Can't use radio as they can't do multiple select .. so I'm sure you meant checkbox

Comment: @LGSon definitely.

Comment: I updated my answer with a _checkbox_ variant as well

Comment: For future users to know, it would be great if you accept an answer, if any, that best solve your question, and if none did, what did we miss or misunderstood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do that...

```js
(function(values,sel) {

  var sel = document.querySelector('select');
  values = new Array(sel.length);

  sel.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    
    values[e.target.index] = !values[e.target.index];    
    for(var i=0;i<values.length;++i) {
      sel.options[i].selected = values[i];
    }

  });

})();
```

```html
<select multiple="multiple">
     <option value="car">car</option>
     <option value="scooter">scooter</option>
     <option value="bus">bus</option>
</select>
```

...and a non script way could be with `checkbox`'s

```css
.check-multiple {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.check-multiple input {
  display: none;
}
.check-multiple label {
  display: block;
}
.check-multiple span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.check-multiple input:checked ~ span {
  background: #03f;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="check-multiple">
     <label><input value="car" type="checkbox"><span>car</span></label>
     <label><input value="scooter" type="checkbox"><span>scooter</span></label>
     <label><input value="bus" type="checkbox"><span>bus</span></label>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [checkboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox). Those are the best HTML element to support selecting multiple options.

You could **write your own** multi-select component in Javascript to mirror popular libraries such as [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), but I wouldn't recommend it due to the time committment.